# Add a query in cloudcreativiy/json-api - laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, adapter, json-api

In my Laravel API (cloudcreativity) I have a Report resource and this one has a field called `created_user`. All the users have a role like `admin`, `level1`, `level2`, and `level3`. I'd like to implement that in all the actions (index, read, filter, sort...).

The `level1` and `level2` only could see the reports of `level1`, `level2` and `level3`. And the `level3` only could see his reports.

So, I need to add a `join` and a `where`. Anyway, I don't know how to implement it and which function I must use. In other words, I need to do a query to select some reports.

Which function must I implement? In the adapter? A specific controller? Can u write the function, please?

I'm not talking about filters. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the logic to exclude certain reports using [Eloquent's scopes feature](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes). The scope could be applied to the query using in the [Laravel JSON:API](https://github.com/cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api#cloudcreativitylaravel-json-api) `Adapter`. This is discussed in detail in *scope* chapter of Laravel JSON:API's [Adapter documentation](https://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/adapters/).

Comment: Thank you jelhan! I've just resolved the issue with scopes.